# display age ranges based on mydb using sql query

Tags: mysql

my db table having two columns name and age .i want to display if age is 21 then agegroup is 20-30,similarly if age is 32 the agegroup is 30-40 in my result display.

i need  sql query to display the result like following

```
                          Name   age    group      

                          A     22    20-30

                          B     45    40-50
```

Comment: @Ullas so you changed the question to look like your answer fit their original problem? It sounds like this person isn't sure of how SQL tables work and you're assuming that they're strictly asking for that output. Does that output even make sense? Why would "age" be in the output if they're trying to determine a group.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ In the question OP mentioned that he/she has a table having two columns called `name` and `age`. And he/she needs an additional column with `ageGroup` in the result. Thats what I did.

Answer (score 1):

In regard to your groups, in the table setup, create a min age column and a max age field in a table that defines your groups.

```
groups    minAge    maxAge
-------------------------------
20-30    20        30
40-50    40        50
```

The SQL create statement would look like this:

```
create table if not exists ageGroups (
  groupName varchar(25),
  minAge INT,
  maxAge INT
  ) ENGINE ndb;

insert into ageGroups (groupName,minAge,maxAge) Values ('20-30',20,30);
insert into ageGroups (groupName,minAge,maxAge) Values ('30-40',30,40);
insert into ageGroups (groupName,minAge,maxAge) Values ('40-50',40,50);


create table if not exists identities (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(45),
  age INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
  ) ENGINE nbd;

insert into identities (name,age) values ("A",22);
insert into identities (name,age) values ("B",45);
```

Then to do your queries you would do search for the where the age value is between the min and max in the ageGroups table:

```
select i.name,i.age,a.groupName from identities i, ageGroups a where i.age > a.minAge and i.age < a.maxAge;
```

## Output

```
NAME    AGE    GROUPNAME
A       22     20-30
B       45     40-50
```

**I've made an [SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0862d1/1).**

Answer (score 0):

I'd just try something like this:

```
SELECT 'name', 'age', FLOOR(age / 10) * 10 AS 'group';
```

This should get you the following result set:

```
name | age | group
-----+-----+------
A    | 22  | 20
B    | 45  | 40
```

You could expand the 'group' column to print a range, but that might complicates things further down the pipe (e.g. when trying to compare or sort), so I'd do that when displaying only.

Answer (score 0):

### **Query**

```
SELECT name, age,
CONCAT(FLOOR(age / 10) * 10,' - ',(FLOOR(age / 10)+1)*10)  AS age_group
FROM tbl;
```

### **[Find Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a00661/2)**